# What's interpretation of "terms objects from R data objects"?

Tags: r

There's a term method in R for which documentation says

> The function terms is a generic function which can be used to extract terms objects from various kinds of R data objects.

What exactly is the `terms` object ?

Answer (score 0):

Treasure hidden inside `?terms.object`

> An object of class terms holds information about a model. Usually the model was specified in terms of a formula and that formula was used to determine the terms object.

Comment: Agree, but it doesn't explain how to define `terms`. Also, how's `terms` used to extract model.frame ?  http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.frame.html

Comment: You can always look at the source to see how this is done (extracting the model.frame).

Comment: Yup, that's what i did. Still clueless as it's making native call to C (.External2)

Comment: Take a look at the source for `terms.formula`, which I believe is typically how the `terms` object is constructed. You can see the source for the C call here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0845e882fc5761f594a896d3918932d1256baa08/src/library/stats/src/model.c#L1632